# Drawing a dotted (circle-shaped!) line

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to use `DashPathEffect` to draw an actual dotted stroke. But the result is unfortunately not a perfect circle.

```
new Paint() {
    setAntiAlias( true )
    setColor( R.color.grey.as[Color] )
    setPathEffect( new DashPathEffect( Array( 0.01f, 5.dp ), 0 ) )
    setStrokeCap( Cap.ROUND )
    setStrokeWidth( 2.dp )
    setStyle( STROKE )
}
```

*(Scala code)*

**100%**

[image: 100%]

**Scaled**

[image: Scaled]
[image: Scaled with grid]

**Without anti-alias (2 and 3dp stroke width)**

[image: Without anti-alias (2dp)]
[image: Without anti-alias (3dp)]

Is it possible to configure the `Paint` object in such a way that the circle shape is correct, rather than drawing the large amount of circles manually?

Comment: The `DashPathEffect` required me to always draw at least 1px (in my case I'm using `0.01f`, but I could as well use 1). And this leads to the shape being 1px too high. No matter what the resolution or pixel density is. When I use 0 instead (hoping only the round stroke caps are drawn) nothing shows up. On a device with a lower pixel density, the malformed circle will therefore be even more obvious.

Comment: It's called `antialiasing`. Try removing this line: `setAntiAlias(true);`

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying problem; but it makes it more obvious. I'll attach a screen without anti-alias for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Yes, antialiasig does this: puts some more colored dots around the "circles", to make it seem more round (or diagonal, in case of oblique lines). Noone will complain if, gigantographed, the trick will become visible.

Comment: I know what anti-alias does. Nobody sane draws circles without anti-alias. The issue is simply that the "circle" is always 1px heigher than wider, the reason for this is apparently how `DashPathEffect` works.